# What does it mean to do data exploration?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have been trying to learn machine learning via a data set consisting of animal positions taken from a tracker (as a GPS is out of financial reach for me). The ultimate aim is to be able to describe their behaviour.

I have found this quite interesting flowchart which helps visualise the main (or general) procedure in performing machine learning (flowchart is at the beginning of page 207):

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0003347216303360

So given raw data, we deal with missing data sets (by ignoring or interpolating linearly, etc). We then use unsupervised methods to accentuate the data's structure. Next we remove uninformative variables (presumably noise, among others, by filtering).

All of these are under 'data exploration'. I get the first and the last steps, since I have done them (interpolating and filtering). But what does the second statement mean: "use unsupervised methods to accentuate the data structure"?

Please give some insights and examples.